# How to call a specific function inside a object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object, prototype

This is a part of my javascript taken from a jquery plugin.
This plugin let me to make a div widgets with remote html content loaded inside and a tools header with a refresh button that reload the remote content.
I need to call a _loadAjaxFile function for reload content from a others functions outside this plugin (for example a button) but I can't to undestand if this is possible and how.

```
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {

    function Plugin(element, options) {
        this.obj = $(element);
        this.o = $.extend({}, $.fn[pluginName].defaults, options);
        this.objId = this.obj.attr('id');
        this.pwCtrls = '.jarviswidget-ctrls';
        this.widget = this.obj.find(this.o.widgets);
        this.toggleClass = this.o.toggleClass.split('|');
        this.editClass = this.o.editClass.split('|');
        this.fullscreenClass = this.o.fullscreenClass.split('|');
        this.customClass = this.o.customClass.split('|');
        this.storage = {enabled: this.o.localStorage};
        this.initialized = false;

        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype = {

    _loadAjaxFile: function (awidget, file, loader) {

            var self = this;

            awidget.find('.widget-body')
                .load(file, function (response, status, xhr) {

                    var $this = $(this);

                    if (status == "error") {
                        $this.html('<h4 class="alert alert-danger">' + self.o.labelError + '<b> ' +
                            xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + '</b></h4>');
                    }

                    if (status == "success") {

                        var aPalceholder = awidget.find(self.o.timestampPlaceholder);

                        if (aPalceholder.length) {

                            aPalceholder.html(self._getPastTimestamp(new Date()));
                        }

                        if (typeof self.o.afterLoad == 'function') {
                            self.o.afterLoad.call(this, awidget);
                        }
                    }

                    self = null;
                });
            this._runLoaderWidget(loader);

        },

    }

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

This is the complete code of the plugin

[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bzka3reC4EpAa3d3S050a2ctOEk?usp=sharing)

Comment: You should be able to call it using `Plugin._loadAjaxFile()`, since _loadAjaxFile is just a method on the Plugin prototype.

Comment: @FranCarstens `Plugin` is not in the global scope, it's local to the IIFE.

Comment: @FranCarstens - And it's not on `Plugin` in any case; it's on `Plugin.prototype`.

Comment: I apologize, I misread that.

Comment: Please show us how you are using that Plugin in your code. Also, is this the complete code? It looks like it's missing the `init` method

Comment: this is the complete code of the plugin
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bzka3reC4EpAa3d3S050a2ctOEk?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

The `_` on it is the author telling you not to call it directly. It doesn't mean you *can't*, but you shouldn't. You'd be using internals that aren't meant to be used directly.

I assume what you've quoted is incomplete, but the fact that that function is on `Plugin.prototype` means you would be able to call it on plugin *instances*. How you get an instance of the plugin to call it on (and whether you can) depends on the plugin (look in its documentation); it may well never expose an instance directly to your code, instead just making its features available via the name it adds to `jQuery.fn`.

Comment: Entirely correct, but that much guesswork maybe should get the question closed :-)

Comment: @Bergi - Sometimes I find it appropriate to both answer and VTC. The only guesswork above is something quite obvious: That the OP has left out a lot of the plugin code.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no documentation of the plugin.

Comment: @danny36 - That combined with the code you've quoted suggests to me you want to find another plugin or write something of your own. But if you keep using this one, you'll have to study its source to see whether there's a way to access an instance.